# Should I make an instance of GUI in Game or the other way around?

Tags: java, user-interface

I have two classes: `GUI` and `Game`, which handle the GUI logic and the game logic respectively.

Should I make an instance of `GUI` in `Game`, or an instance of `Game` in `GUI`.

If it makes any difference: it's Java.

Some more explanation:

I'm making a game of life clone in Java, but I'm running into some issues with updating my GUI. Before continuing to solve those issues, I want to know what the proper way is to use a GUI.

Comment: Do you expect people infer from just the names of your classes?

Comment: @ivanovic Yep he thinks we're that good :) but one step forward if it is a swing gui remember that if you pause your logic and your gui was not run in thread it will be stopped as well.

Comment: look at this, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: You need to make an instance of GUI inside GUI using the instance-ception method.

Comment: Instead of sarcastic comments, you could have also asked for more info. How would i know what you need, when I'm clearly a noob and barely know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither.

I would recommend you to build your application following the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) idiom.

The game state (model) and the visual representation of it (view) should not depend on each other. Both should be created and manipulated by a controller (or multiple controllers).

This application design has the advantage that you can easily make changes to one of the components (or even replace them completely) without having to touch the other.

Comment: So basically, I need a third class (my main program) that instances my game and GUI class? My main program can then dispatch commands to the other two classes?

Comment: Thats what I thought also :-)

Comment: @Simon Verbeke: Exactly. Your main program would be the controller in this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you can regard your application as layered. The UI layer can be assumed to be "above" the application layer. With regard to dependencies, this is interpeted so that the `UI` can depend on the `Game`, bot not the other way round.

You can think of it this way - "what part should I be able to change without forcing the other one to change as well?" My guess is that you would like to be able to change the `UI` without changing the `Game`. It makes considerably less sense the other way round. So again the consequence would be that the `UI` should depend on the `Game` and contain a reference to it.

EDIT: with regard to the MVC architecture. Using MVC does not mean that the view may retrieve it's values from the model only over a controller. The values should be changed using a controller, but the view often still has a reference to the model to display it. The controller usually has no added value for model diplay.